# Rewrite code in Caliburn. Micro

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, mvvm

There is this code uses in LandingPage.xaml.cs

```
private void LoadUserInfo()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);

        fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            string ert;
            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                var profilePictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type={1}&access_token={2}", App.FacebookId, "square", App.AccessToken);

                BitmapImage qwer = new BitmapImage(new Uri(profilePictureUrl));
                ert = String.Format("{0} {1}", (string)result["first_name"], (string)result["last_name"]);
            });

        };

        fb.GetTaskAsync("me");
    }
```

I want to rewrie this code with Caliburn.Micro(MVVM).

But i have problems in replace it on work code.

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
              {
 });
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see how this is Caliburn.Micro related and I do not think you even need the Dispatcher, but you can replace `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` with `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

Comment: I replace. but this string dont execute 

db._fbcontacts.InsertOnSubmit(new FacebookContactsList { Name = FBName });

Without Dispatcher app falls